# create list of activemq queue

Tags: activemq-classic

my existing code which uses BlockingQueue creates a list of BlockingQueue (like private List> queues;) in which I can put messages to process.
However due to persistence issue we plan to shift to activemq.
Can anyone please help me if we can get a list of activemq queue (in java program not from configuration file). I know that I can use createQueue on session to create a single instance of the queue but I want list of queue like done for BlockingQueue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list of queues, you have to create that list, then create each queue individually from the session object.

`Queue q = session.createQueue("someQueueName")`

This, however, does not really "create" a queue in that sense, since a queue is a persistent "thing" in the ActiveMQ process/server. This will only create a reference to an ActiveMQ queue given an identifier/name.

I'm not sure why you need ten queues right up. Typically, you have one queue per event type or use case (or similar), then use concurrent consumers to process in parallel.

But of course, you can always do somethings similar by a simple for loop, creating one queue at a time and attaching them to an arraylist. Note that you cannot get type safe queues with only `Event` objects in them.

You can send `ObjectMessage`s with events though. Just create one:

```
Event event = createEvent(..); // Given "Event" is serializable (need to be able to persist it).
Message m = session.createObjectMessage(event);
// Send message as usual in ActiveMQ.
```

It might be that you need to rethink one or a few things in your code when converting from BlockingQueues to persistent ActiveMQ queues.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of the available queues using DestinationSource from your connection.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection)connectionFactory.createConnection();
DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();
```

edit:
to create a queue take a look at ActiveMQ Hello world sample [link](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html) What the code does there is creating a connection to an activeMQ-broker embedded in the jvm

```
// Create a ConnectionFactory
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

// Create a Connection
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

// Create a Session
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");
```

The thing that might not be obvious with above code is that the line:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
```

will not only setup a connection to a broker, but embedded a broker inside the connection if there isn't one already. Explained at the bottom of [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html)

That feature can be turned of using (you need a broker, but if you want to set it up in other way):

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?create=false");
```

I really like ActiveMQ, but it offers a lot more than persistence, so things might seem a little overly complex when doing the simple things. But hope that will not scare you.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. I meant creating a list of queue like
List<BlockingQueue<Event>> queues = new ArrayList<BlockingQueue<Event>>(10);
which would create a list of 10 blocking queue.
can the same be done for activemq (creating a list of 10 activemq queues)?

Comment: on the connection object you got some methods for creating queues in your broker. ill add some example tonight if you havnt figured it out by then (cant code with phone yet :))

Comment: Thank you very much Aksel for your reply, however I am not sure if the code above give me an option to create a list of activemq queues. As I mentioned, while using BlockingQueue I created a list of queue with following code:
List<BlockingQueue<Event>> queues = new ArrayList<BlockingQueue<Event>>(10);

which created a list of 10 BlockingQueues. I was wondering if I could create a list of 10 (or any number) of activemq in the same manner. I want multiple queues to process my event instead of processing my events with only one queue.

Comment: In ActiveMQ what you need to do is to have multiple consumers that consume messages from a queue, but you should only have one Queue if i understand your scenario correctly

Comment: agreed but what if I want to create separate queue for each consumer type. say for consumer type1, queue 1 and so on... in that case I will have to create more than one queue.
one thing i can do is creating more than one queue in for loop but I am not sure how can I do that. Thanks for your help and patience