# Is it possible to get a list of queues on a remote broker?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of existing queues on a remote broker.

It looks like I can listen to queues as they are created/destroyed by adding an advisory message (which I don't yet have working) but I need to get all EXISTING queues on startup.

It looks like I can do this with getDestinationMap:

[http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/Region.html#getDestinationMap()](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/Region.html#getDestinationMap%28%29)

But that seems like it can only be called from an embedded and in-process broker.

I mean... I'm willing to go that route but it seems to make more sense to just have the normal init/daemon setup for activemq and then have a remote process connect to it like a normal JMS consumer.

This documentation seems to imply that it's possible:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-see-what-destinations-are-used.html

But that's by using a Region object and that only seems possible if you're in the same JVM as activemq.

Answer (score 9):

```
    // Create a ConnectionFactory
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

// Create a Connection
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();


//Important point that was missed in the above answer
connection.start();

DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();

for(ActiveMQQueue queue : queues){
    try {
        System.out.println(queue.getQueueName());
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer, `connection.start();` is essential to make it work

Comment: TL;DR : Make sure you cast Connection to `(ActiveMQConnection)`.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021722/3735747

If you're doing this in Java, there's the DestinationSource class that will help:  http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.7.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/advisory/DestinationSource.html

Create a connection and use the ActiveMQConnection type instead of the JMS Connection type.

```
// Create a ConnectionFactory
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

// Create a Connection
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

Once you're connected, you can create a DestinationSource object and get the queues:

```
DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();

for(ActiveMQQueue queue : queues){
    try {
        System.out.println(queue.getQueueName());
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow.. fascinating.  I'm on 5.9.1 and that method isn't there... there's get Topic() but no getQueues()

Comment: Actually .. mea culpa. It's there.  I think this was just an intellij bug.

Comment: ok.. so the method is there.. but the code doesn't work.  this paste bin(http://pastebin.com/BCjfSGyc) returns zero queues....

Comment: For this to work you must have advisory support enabled on both the client and the broker.

Comment: @TimBish advisory feature is enabled by default, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled by default on the Broker

Comment: as @Udara Seneviratne pointed out in her answer, there should be a 'connection.start();' line. At least  that made it work for me.